# Python: Finding period of a two column data

Tags: python, fft, dft

This question seems so trivial but I didn't find any suitable answer so I am asking!

Lets say I have a two column data(say, {x, sin(x)} )

`X Y(X)
0.0 0.0
0.1 0.099
0.2 0.1986`

How do I find the period of the function Y(X);

I have some experience in Mathematica where(roughly)

1. I just interpolate the data as a function say y(x), then
2. Calculate y'(x) and set y'(x_p)=0;
3. collect all (x_p+1 - x_p)'s and take average to get the period.

In python, however I am stuck after step 1 as I can find out x_p for a particular guess value but not all the x_p's. Also this procedure doesn't seem very elegant to me. Is there a better way to do things in python?

Comment: Do you only have 3 datapoints? If not, how are your x values distributed? Also, do you have "noiseless" data or does the algorithm have to be robust to noise? How important is speed to you?

Comment: I have more data points...say 100K or more. x values are for example numpy.linspane(0, 10000, 100000). and you can take sin(x) as a prototype. I don't need to take care of any noise, and speed is important but solving the problem is now priority.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating periods I would just find the peak of the Fourier transformed data, to do that in python look into script.fft. Could be computationally intensive though.

Comment: Can you please add some detail and if possible an example showing how to find the period of a data(say, {x, sin(x)}).

Comment: will your time steps be equidistant?

Comment: Yeah, time steps will be equidistant.

Comment: in that case, you will get the second column of your data (i.e. data[:,1]) and run the script.fft not that and find the maximum argument:
`argmax(scipy.fft(data[:,1]))` You will have to rescale that by deviding by the largest value for x

Comment: edit: you will want the largert absolute value, i.e.

`argmax(abs(scipy.fft(data[:,1])))/max(data[0:]`

Comment: Oh I forgot about the sampling frequency peak.
try to take the first half of `abs(scipy.fft(data[:,1]))` array and from that find the maximum argument